# Use MacOS Drawing APIs for console-application drawing?

Tags: swift, macos

I have recently came to like SwiftUI and Swift as a programming language. Although, most coding I do does not involve full-fledged user interfaces. For my next project I would like to write a console application that draws images. Since I am using it on my mac only, I wonder whether I can just use Swift and MacOS's drawing APIs without running a GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can - [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics) (which used to be known as Quartz) is the underlying library that's available on macOS, and relatively easily invoked to draw or manipulate images as you like. It supports generating raster image files (PNG, TIFF, JPEG) as well as vector (PDF).